# Why do I get error for weatherIcon.src and weatherIcon.alt?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am beginner of JS. I cannot figure it out why do I get error on my weatherIcon.src and weatherIcon.alt? It should show the tempurature, but It does not...

```js
fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
     const locationName = data.name;
      const temp = Math.floor(data.main.temp);
      const iconCode = data.weather[0].icon;
      const description = data.weather[0].description;
      weatherIcon.alt = description;
      weatherIcon.src = `img/${iconCode}.png`;
      weatherLocation.innerText = locationName;
      weatherTemperature.innerText = `${temp}°`;
      descriptionElement.innerText = getDescription(iconCode);
      htmlElement.classList.remove("js-loading");
    });
```

Comment: First of all: Mind to share *WHAT* error you get? Second, please read how to properly format code on stackoverflow. It is a basic form of politeness to present a somehow readable question to anybody who is willing to spend their time helping you.

Comment: What is weatherIcon? you need to declare this variable as document.querySelector('')?

Comment: You are accessing mutliple variables without having them declared ...

Comment: Sorry about not describing enough. I am new to stack overflow and a beginner at programming. Please allow me to learn. So I receive an error as "app.js:32 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'alt')
    at app.js:32:23".

Comment: Well, where and how do you define and assign `weatherIcon`? The error seems pretty clear, `weatherIcon === null`

Comment: This code is part of code `const weatherIcon = document.querySelector(".weather-icon");`

Comment: Well is there any element with class `weather-icon`? If yes, is this element already there, when this code is executed? That `weatherIcon === null` suggests, that one of these questions has to be  answered with "No" ...  Hint: If this code is executed in the header of your HTML file, there won't be any elements yet, where the `querySelector` could select from ...

Comment: Please update the question with some example data and enough html and code to reproduce the problem.